# How to make gray-colored text in ConTeXt beta?

Tags: color, context, context-mkiv

As I know, in ConTeXt stable, one can use `\color[gray:3]{}` to display the text inside the brackets with a very light gray color, e.g.:

```
\setupcolor[rgb]
\starttext
    \color[gray:3]{This is some text.}
\stoptext
```

After upgrading to ConTeXt beta, this no longer works in my document. `\color[red]{}`, however, does change the text to red.

- Was the syntax for creating gray colors changed in recent betas?
- How can I create a range of gray colors (from white to black) using numbers in ConTeXt?

Comment: I think we'll need a bit of a clue on versions here

Comment: I have ConTeXt version 2012.08.14. I followed the instructions here: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Colors#Choosing_a_color_model

Comment: What about defining the colour with `\definecolor[gray:3][s=.8]`? You can also have a look at [`\definepalet`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definepalet)

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. Seems to be a regression bug. Please report this to the context mailing list.

Comment: Bug aside, you can iterate through the X11 color definitions to achieve the grayscale gradient: ``\setupcolor [x11] \dostepwiserecurse{100}{0}{-1}{\color[gray\recurselevel]{foo\space}}``. The value determines the percentage of white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the solution of  Philipp Gesang of the context mailing list:

Use `\setupcolor[dem]` to get scaled colors.

```
\setupcolor[dem]

\starttext
  \framed[background=color, backgroundcolor=gray:3]{testing}
\stoptext
```

(I am using background color so that the result is easier to visualize).